# Can I have a pipe character inside the argument of \lstinline?

Tags: listings, inline

I'm using the Listings package and I wanted to ask whether it is possible to use the pipe character `|` with the `\lstinline` command as it uses the pipe as beginning and ending character.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Here's some text and an if-statement: \lstinline|if(a == 5 || b == 3)|. %Not working as lstinline stops after the first character of the 'or'-sign |
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Use another delimiter for `\lstinline`, e.g., `\lstinline+if(a == 5 || b == 3)+`

Comment: Can I use _any_ delimiter??

Comment: [listings documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf), section 1.2 says the delimiter can be any character not in the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for this hint - apparently ) haven't read the documentation _that_ carefully ^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) (section **4.2 Typesetting listings**):

> ```
> \lstinline[<key=value list>]<character><source code><same character>
> ```
>
> works like `\verb` but respects the active language and style. These listings
>   use flexible columns unless requested differently in the optional argument,
>   and do not support frames or background colors. You can write
>   `\lstinline!var i:integer;!` and get `var i:integer;`.
>   Since the command first looks ahead for an optional argument, you must
>   provide at least an empty one if you want to use `[` as `<character>`.

So, as long as you use `<character>` you have to use the `<same character>` to close the inline listing (except for the experimental `{`...`}` usage). Choose whichever character doesn't conflict with your inline usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
Here's some text and an if-statement: \lstinline!if(a == 5 || b == 3)!.

Or there is \lstinline+if(a != 3 && b !=3 || c != 4)+.
\end{document}
```